# validates_inclusion_of :in => [true, false] is allowing Strings and Fixnums

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, boolean

I have this validation in my model:

```
validates_inclusion_of :imported, :in => [true, false]
```

but still allows Strings and Fixnums.  This Shoulda macro returns 2 failures:

```
should_not_allow_values_for :imported, "blah", 42
```

and I've checked that the macro isn't at fault by doing this in a test:

```
@item.imported = 42
assert !@item.save
```

and I get this failure:

```
<false> is not true.
```

Here is the relevant line in schema.rb:

```
t.boolean  "imported"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is outdated now, so I hope you found an answer, but here's the comprehensive story on another question I answered:

[Rails: Validating inclusion of a boolean fails tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170008/rails-validating-inclusion-of-a-boolean-fails-tests/5171074#5171074)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm sure someone doing a search and coming across this will very much appreciate it.