# Validate boolean fields in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I need to validate boolean fields for a Rails ActiveRecord object. I used the common solution to this problem:

```
validates :boolean_field, :inclusion => { :in => [true, false] }
```

But although this solutions solves the problem with validating `false` values, it still allows to save strings to the `boolean_field`:

```
my_object.boolean_field = "string"
my_object.save # => true
my_object.boolean_field # => false
```

Why does this happen if I specified the inclusion to `[true, false]`? And more importantly, how do I validate **only** true and false values?

P.S. If it is important to the question, I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170008/rails-validating-inclusion-of-a-boolean-fails-tests might help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can validate by checking datatype, you can use `is_a?` and pass class name of the datatype as a parameter

```
pry(main)> a = "aaaaa"
=> "aaaaa"
pry(main)> a.is_a?(Boolean)
=> false
```

Since it was a string it returned `false`, now try for boolean

```
pry(main)> b = true
=> true
pry(main)> b.is_a?(Boolean)
=> true
```

Add a custom validation by using this logic

```
validate :check_boolean_field

def check_boolean_field
  errors.add(...) unless boolean_field.is_a?(Boolean)
end
```