# Rails 4 validates_inclusion_of and shoulda_matchers test work weird

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, shoulda

I have this validation in my model `violin.rb`:

```
  validates :bow_included, presence: true
  validates_inclusion_of :bow_included, in: [true, false]
```

And in my spec file `violin_spec.rb` I have the following (I use `shoulda_matchers` gem):

```
it { should validate_presence_of :bow_included }
it { should validate_inclusion_of(:bow_included).in_array([true, false]) }
```

When I run the test, I get this:

> 1) Violin validations should ensure inclusion of bow_included in
>   [true, false]
>
> ```
>  Failure/Error: it { should validate_inclusion_of(:bow_included).in_array([true, false]) }
>    [true, false] doesn't match array in validation
>  # ./spec/models/violin_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```

However, I have the same validation and test in another model and there it works fine.

Could you please help me find out what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at their documentation, they say that they don't recommend this and that it will produce warnings: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_inclusion_of_matcher.rb#L52

The tl;dr is:

> There is never a case where a boolean column will be anything but
>   true, false, or nil, as ActiveRecord will type-cast an incoming value
>   to one of these three values. That means there isn't any way we can
>   refute this logic in a test.

I know that doesn't answer your question directly, but if you're using boolean values in your AR models, then those tests aren't necessary anyway.

Comment: Well, I thought I needed tests because for boolean columns the test like this: `it { should allow_value("whatever").for(:bow_included) }` passes without any problems.

Comment: That just gets type-cast to true, if memory serves.

Comment: This is more thoroughly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170008/rails-validating-inclusion-of-a-boolean-fails-tests