# .sample returns nil when seeding Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm building a Rails application and I've encountered a really odd bug. The code `[true false].sample` is never supposed to return blank. However, it sometimes does so when running `rake db:seed`.

In my application I have a Store model that has presence validations:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :accepts_credit, :parking
end
```

I also run a test in rspec like this (that always passes)

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Store, type: :model do 
  it { should validate_presence_of :accepts_credit }  
  it { should validate_presence_of :parking        }  
end
```

Now, in my seeds file I have

```
Store.create(
  ...
  accepts_credit: [false, true].sample(1),
  parking:      %w[lots some none].sample(1),
  ... 
)
```

Running this in the terminal with `rake db:reset --trace`, I get errors that the store wasn't created.  I inspected this by running `Store.create!` instead of `Store.create` which causes the terminal to display errors.`Validation failed: Accepts credit can't be blank`.

Now, I'm relatively new to Rails but I don't understand why the sample method `.sample` could return blank.  According to the docs: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample, sample always returns an element from the array.

**Edit**

I've used `.sample` in replace of `.sample(1)` as well.

What am I missing?  Is `.blank` doing what I think it is?

Answer (score 0):

`false.blank?` is `true` (i.e. not "present"), so you'll need to rewrite your validation if you want to persist `false` values. You might try `validates_inclusion_of :accepts_credit, in: [true, false]` if you want to protect against `nil`.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense and was my first intuition but the shoulda-matchers docs said that you shouldn't use inclusion on booleans.  Here's the link to the docs: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_inclusion_of_matcher.rb.

Comment: On second thought, I guess that answers the question.  You shouldn't validate presence of booleans because AR will typecast them in.  Your answer makes since on understanding what AR is doing.  Thanks!

Comment: AR will typecast values once records have been pulled from the DB, so `Store.last.accepts_credit?` will work as expected regardless of the inclusion validation. Nonetheless, it could be important to ensure you don't have `NULL` values in boolean fields because queries like `Store.where(accepts_credit: false)` will not return such records. `FALSE` != `NULL` in the DB.

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170008/rails-validating-inclusion-of-a-boolean-fails-tests/10942223#10942223

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That's a great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have forgot to run migrations. I think you were supposed to run: rake db:migrate:reset

Try to run, rake db:migrate, and then, rake db:seed.
I apologize ahead of time if this answer does not help.

Comment: It is my understanding that `rake db:reset` drops the database, creates it, and runs all migrations in order then seeds it.